# Error: Invalid JSON RPC response | ropsten.infura

Tags: contract-deployment, ropsten, truffle-migration, infura

I'm trying to deploy my contracts to the ropsten test network, but I get this error.

the message error :

```
C:\Users\acer\test>truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten
Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0xf9d9daf3c904e239bc27fd70a51916e1dd954238215f631e7f341e1270fa55ab
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\acer\test\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:35:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\acer\test\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:115:32)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\acer\test\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:76:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\acer\test\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:422:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (C:\Users\acer\test\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:669:14)
    at ClientRequest.request.on (C:\Users\acer\test\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:499:23)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  Migrations: 0x116940816fb03041b4fc9018dffdef346fe0932b
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_migration.js
  Replacing DinarCoin...
  ... 0x8b1ddbc08abb3561be6df6148a7a5cf9006e1e6ae520dd9e8a67713ed6af33cd
  DinarCoin: 0xeb43d979ec0d3d004c5d50c202e2cbec02edf2e1
Saving artifacts...
  Deploying DinarCrowdsale...
  ... 0x949fff0717b07829fd62f5df0fb9f21ad1ed2d4b9665704c75aab206fcf49921
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\acer\test\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:35:16)
```

Please How can I fix this problem ? and Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you add your truffle config network settings for ropsten

Comment: @SanjaySB  I set up a  HDWalletProvider and connect it to infura and ropeston testnet

Comment: The error could be in the migration code or the config set up. Without sharing anything how can one debug your code.

Comment: truffle-config.js :

Comment: @SanjaySB Sir, when I deploy to ganache local testnet, is work without problem !!!

Comment: @SanjaySB you can check truffle config and migration files below .

Answer (score 0):

@SanjaySB,

truffle-config.js  file :

```
require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*', // eslint-disable-line camelcase
    },
    ganache: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*', // eslint-disable-line camelcase
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(
          process.env.MNEMONIC,
          `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/9ffa4f404f6c47bf9dd98937dc4dee36`
        )
      },
      gas: 5000000,
      gasPrice: 25000000000,
      network_id: 3, 
      skipDryRun: true  
    },
    rinkeby: {
        provider: function() { 
         return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/9ffa4f404f6c47bf9dd98937dc4dee36");
        },
        network_id: 4,
        gas: 4500000,
        gasPrice: 10000000000,
    }

  },
  solc: {

    version: "0.4.24",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 200  // Optimize for how many times you intend to run the code
        },

      }
  }
};
```

Migration file ;

```
module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const _name = "Dinar Coin";
  const _symbol = "DNC";
  const _decimals = 18 ;
  await deployer.deploy(DinarCoin, _name, _symbol, _decimals);
  const deployedToken = await DinarCoin.deployed();

  const latestTime = (new Date).getTime();

  const _rate           = 500;
  const _wallet         = '0x7b179f369451782679aCc04f9799193E67f14f74'; // TODO: Replace me
  const _token          = deployedToken.address;
  const _openingTime    = latestTime + duration.minutes(1);
  const _closingTime    = _openingTime + duration.weeks(10);
  const _cap            = ether(100);
  const _goal           = ether(50);
  const _foundersFund   = '0x7b179f369451782679aCc04f9799193E67f14f74'; // TODO: Replace me
  const _foundationFund = '0x7b179f369451782679aCc04f9799193E67f14f74'; // TODO: Replace me
  const _partnersFund   = '0x7b179f369451782679aCc04f9799193E67f14f74'; // TODO: Replace me
  const _releaseTime    = _closingTime + duration.days(1);

  await deployer.deploy(
    DinarCrowdsale,
    _rate,
    _wallet,
    _token,
    _cap,
    _openingTime,
    _closingTime,
    _goal,
    _foundersFund,
    _foundationFund,
    _partnersFund,
    _releaseTime
  );

  return true;
};
```